# Magento external Script and Session

Tags: session, magento

I want to add an external script which gets a sku via GET check the ID and then redirect to the cart if available otherwise it sets en error and also redirecting to the cart.
The script is called from a product page:

```
 http://myhost/scripts/addto.php?sku=12345
```

Here is the colmplete code

```
 <?php
    include_once '../../../../../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));      
    $sku = $_GET['sku']; 
    if (!isset($_GET['qty'])) { $qty = '1'; } else { $qty = $_GET['qty']; }
    $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
    if ($id == '') {
        $id = $sku;
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError("Product not found!");
    }
```

Works fine, but after logout and relogin the error message is missing. I found out that's because of a cookie which is set. After deleting that cookie the error message is working again after relogin.

Answer (score 0):

What does not work?

You logout and login and then the script stop working? So the session is not found? The product ist not found? The product is not loaded? The user is not forwarded? :-)

Sure it does not. The Message is a Notice. If it is shown once, it is deleted.

What behaviour do you want?

Comment: ok, sorry. it doesn't show the error message after redirecting to the cart. i can change the browser it works one time then relogin and it doesn't show it again.

Comment: Cookie set? I don't know what you are talking about :-/ What cookie is set?

Answer (score 0):

use `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Product not found!");`, maybe checkout/session is user specific...

cheers